# Purely-imaginary Harmonic function on hyperbolic space is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, complex-geometry

Suppose I have a function
$$
f: \mathbb H^3 \to \mathbb C
$$
that is harmonic and whose image can be shown to be purely imaginary. Is it possible to deduce that it is in fact constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If we write $\mathbb H^3=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 \, \vert \, z>0\} $ then in coordinates $$ \Delta u =z^2 \bigg ( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x ^2}+ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2}\bigg ) -z \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} .$$ By inspection, $u(x,y,z) =ix$ is harmonic with purely imaginary image, but is not constant.